# Get all tables using sequelize postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using postgresql as database and sequelize for ORM.
I am new to postgresql and even in sequelize.
Here is my code :

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize("postgres://postgres:root@localhost:5432/databaseName", {
    logging: false
  });
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(()=>console.log("Connected"))
  .catch(err=> console.log(err))
```

Comment: Welcome! What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually i wanted to get all the table details (access all the tables) in my database using Sequelize.
I have already made the connection by creating object after that how to proceed i am not getting that.